# Can we please make "Genitive" a synonym of "Possessive"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

They are the [same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case). There's no reason to have two tags.

Tag [genitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genitive) (17 questions) is significantly less-used than the tag [possessive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessive) (104 questions), so it seems that [possessive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessive) should be the primary.

Comment: If someone will point me to the right place I'll suggest it or vote for it or whatever it takes to support this proposal.

Comment: @StoneyB you suggest it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/possessive/synonyms). I only have four upvotes in the tag (five are needed), so I can't suggest it myself... and I probably can't vote on it but that's the link you need.

Comment: As you wish! It's done.

Comment: I've up-voted both the proposed synonym and one of your "possessive" tag answers (which I would have up-voted if I had come across it) so you should be able to vote for the synonym also.

Comment: Thanks @ColleenV I noticed that a bit ago and went ahead and upvoted already. I think I actually have 6 upvotes now, so it wasn't only your vote that got me from 4 to the 5 I needed :D

Comment: Glad that's sorted out - we do have a pretty awesome community around here, don't we?

Comment: Naturally, the system won't let me vote on the synonym suggestion. Apparently, I don't know the necessary magic incantation. :/

Comment: @Martha Some other users voted, and the synonym is now live.

Answer (score -2):

Despite the venerable support gained for this proposal, I heartily disagree that *genitive* and *possessive* are the same thing. The term *genitive* covers a kind of grammatical inflection that contrasts with *nominative, accusative* and *plain case*. Possessive covers a kind of semantic relationship between two things. There's no such thing as a possessive case in English, and nouns entering into possessive constructions are not necessarily genitive, they can be plain case. It's also not really helpful to talk about the subjects of gerund-participle clauses as being *accusative* or *possessive*.

Please don't destroy this tag!

Comment: I would agree if most (if not all) of the questions weren't actually about the possessive form...

Comment: @Catija Which possessive form?

Comment: Clearly there is such a thing, regardless of how much you deny it. If you want to make an argument for switching the direction of the synonym, go ahead but there is no reason for two tags to exist which are used for the same exact case. The reality is, 104 vs 17 is a big difference... most people use the term "possessive".

Comment: @Catija My comment implies that there is more than one such thing not less than one such thing. I think your getting a bit overheated?

Comment: @Catija I've had a look at the tagged questions and concur that they'd mostly be just as good under "possessives". I still find your comment unfriendly.

Comment: I think you are technically correct that there is a difference between genetive and possessive, but in practice on this site, the distinction isn't particularly useful. I'd argue the opposite for EL&U though.

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm afraid I detect no consistent or consensus distinction between *possessive* and *genitive* of use among even linguists,much less pedagogues. Alongside the ACC-/POSS-gerund guys, many of the folks who restrict *genitive* to something caselike a) acknowledge that it isn't really a "case" in a technical sense (if *case* **has** a technical sense), and b) speak unembarassedly of both *-'s* and *of-* "genitives", -which for me is quite as nonsensical as the linguist's "dative alternation" and the layman's "perfect tenses" ...

Comment: ... Everybody seems to agree that *genitive* and *possessive* **ought** to mean different things; but until they can agree what different things they **do** mean, I see no point in distinguishing between the devils and the demons dancing on our pinheads.

Comment: @StoneyB Can you provide a citation for the 'a) acknowledge that it isn't really a "case" in a technical sense' claim, please.

Comment: The visible chunks of [this]( https://books.google.com/books?id=gBegIwquwRYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), pp. 9-13, and [this]( https://books.google.com/books?id=eIv1MgCJgkwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Taylor+Possessives&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjskvzb04fKAhWDLmMKHUroAfYQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Taylor%20Possessives&f=false), Ch. 5.

Comment: @StoneyB I think that everyone would agree that *the dog of that particular owner* is a possessive construction but contains no genitive case noun or noun phrase.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: ***I*** agree, of course, and so do you, as do all right-thinking people.  I'd just as soon see em all classified as possessives (or even better, owning forms) and leave the Latin grammar to Latin grammarians.

Comment: @StoneyB Those are all dealing with common nouns and not pronouns. It's the pronouns which are the most casified and also mentioned in my post. OK, actually having reread my post, they are what I just assumed I'd magically talked about without mentioning them :/ The plain case stuff was me trying to ice a cake (when I hadn't made the cake yet).

Comment: Even with the personal pronouns, though, you've got two systems of "inflection", the determinatives and the fused determinatives -- are they both "genitive"?

Comment: I agree with ColleenV: on a site for *English* language learners, quibbling about the difference between English possessive and English genitive is not particularly helpful.

Comment: I once tried to show on ELL that English genitives can be used to express all sorts of semantic relationships other than possession, and I was met with confusion. It seemed that people wanted to define *possession* as 'any semantic relationship that can be indicated by a genitive form'.  In the end, I don't know if I managed to help or if I just confused people further :-(

Comment: The tag synonym went live, and the [tag:genitive] tag is no more.  Let's use the [tag:possession] tag if we need to talk about the semantic relationship "A possesses B".

Comment: I've been thinking about this ... since nowadays we generally speak of subject(ive) and object(ive) case rather than nominative and accusative case, might not the best term for these be **determinative** and **fused-determinative** cases -- which would keep the category syntactic rather than semantic and exclude the (to my mind) quite different "*of* genitives"?

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm, I have never before heard someone describe any statement that expresses ownership as "possessive". If I say, "I own a pencil", there is no "possessive" in that sentence. Rather, "possessive" has traditionally been understood to refer to a category of words that indicate association, namely, words with an apostrophe-s add, possessive pronouns like "my" and "your", and a few other special cases. I comprehend why some want to call this "genitive" rather than "possessive" to avoid being misleading. ...

Comment: ... If I say "The U.S. is my country", obviously I don't mean that I own the entire country. Maybe linguists use the term "possessive" in a different sense, but that is certainly not how I or my children were taught grammar. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your point.